# Yagmail converts message body to base 64

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, yagmail

I sent an email with the following python code:

```
import yagmail, sha, sys, os
os.system('stty -echo')
password = raw_input('Gmail password: ')
os.system('stty echo')
print ''
if not sha.sha(password).hexdigest() == 'digest_of_the_password':
    print 'Password Declined'
    sys.exit()
yag = yagmail.Connect('me@gmail.com', password)
yag.send('to@example.com', 'Hi', "G'day")
```

The subject came out as 'Hi', but the body came out 'RydkYXk='. I installed yagmail with the command: `sudo pip install yagmail` in  my mac terminal.

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm terribly sorry as the maintainer!

I accidentally added a tab in the wrong line, which added the `base64` encoding also to text!

If you would now use `sudo pip install -U yagmail` it will upgrade to the new version where this has been resolved.

For future bugs, please file them at [github](https://github.com/kootenpv/yagmail), I will try to resolve all issues within 24 hours from posting.

Note that now you can simply omit the password: it will save it safely in the keyring after prompting you for the password once. That would save you many lines in this case:

```
import yagmail
yag = yagmail.SMTP('me@gmail.com')
yag.send('to@example.com', 'Hi', "G'day")
```

Comment: This is hilarious and awesome. Thanks at least for being active on SO.